# Idiomatic way to loop over array in Clojure

Tags: python, clojure

I am new to clojure and some how I find simple array manipulations which are easy in python too hard to do in clojure. For example, what is an idiomatic way to do this in clojure?

```
for i = 1 to len(arr)-1:
  sum[i] = arr[i-1] + i
```

Comment: Clojure has specialized functions for working with native Java arrays, which I doubt is what you're asking about here. Please consider rephrasing this question if you're indeed talking about more general list or sequence operations.

Comment: Try taking a look at https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/07/24/sequence-abstractions-in-clojure/ or one of the many excellent Clojure books out there.

Comment: The Python `for` statement is invalid (out of date?): try `for i in range(1, len(arr)): ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure has a nice set of [sequence manipulation](http://clojure.org/sequences) functions that are often helpful for these common tasks. this example would be `(map-indexed + arr)`

```
user> (def arr [1 2 38 2 3 9 4 2])
#'user/arr
user> (map-indexed + arr)
(1 3 40 5 7 14 10 9)
```

though that's just because of the specific example you chose. A more general answer would be to use `map`, `mapv`, `reduce`, or `reductions` or `for` for this sort of thing. For instance:

```
user> (for [i (range 0 (count arr))] (+ i (arr i)))
(1 3 40 5 7 14 10 9)
```

Comment: Did you try the Python code? As given, I can't get it to compile (on Python 2.7.6 - current for Ubuntu). Once the syntax is corrected, it gives  results different from yours (see  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24929270/1562315)). And consider that the Python code does not ascribe a value to `sum[0]`, whereas you do.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, let's do [@ArthurUlfeldt's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24922409/1562315) in Python.

```
arr = [1, 2, 38, 2, 3, 9, 4, 2]
```

and, say

```
sum = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Executing the (corrected/updated?) Python

```
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
   sum[i] = arr[i-1] + i
```

... gives us

```
sum
;[None, 2, 4, 41, 6, 8, 15, 11]
```

To convert this to Clojure, displace the Python index by 1, giving

```
for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
   sum[i+1] = arr[i] + (i+1)
```

Now we can construct the right-hand side as

```
(map + (butlast arr) (iterate inc 1))
;(2 4 41 6 8 15 11)
```

... which we convert to a vector, starting at index 1:

```
(vec (cons nil (map + (butlast arr) (iterate inc 1))))
;[nil 2 4 41 6 8 15 11]
```

We probably want to bind this *value* in a `let` form:

```
(let [sum (vec (cons nil (map + (butlast arr) (iterate inc 1))))]
  #_( ... use `sum` here))
```